# any doable approach to use multiple GPUs, multiple process with tensorflow?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, parallel-processing, gpu

I am using docker container to run my experiment. I have multiple GPUs available and I want to use all of them for my experiment. I mean I want to utilize all GPUs for one program. To do so, I used `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` that suggested on tensorflow site, but it is not working. here is the [full error messages on gist](https://gist.github.com/adamFlyn/5c2e2797f78acfc0136eeb283bb2ec77).

here is available GPUs info:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:6A:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   31C    P8    15W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:6B:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   31C    P8    15W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:6C:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P8    15W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:6D:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   34C    P8    15W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**my current attempt**

here is my attempt using `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy`:

```
device_type = "GPU"
devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices(device_type)
devices_names = [d.name.split("e:")[1] for d in devices]
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(devices=devices_names[:3])

with strategy.scope():
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

The above attempt is not working and gave the error that listed on above gist. I don't find another way of using multiple GPUs for a single experiment.

does anyone any workable approach to make this happens? any thoughts?

Comment: Please add the error in the SO post, as the external gist doesn't exists anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Is the MirrordStrategy proper way to distribute the workload

The approach is correct, as long as the GPUs are on the same host. The TensorFlow [manual](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras) has examples how the `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` can be used with keras to train the MNIST set.

#### Is it the MirrordStrategy the only strategy

No, there are multiple strategies that can be used to acheive the workload distribution.  For example, the `tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy` can also be used to distribute the work on multiple devices trough multiple workers.

The TF [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) explains the strategies, the limitations associated with the strategies and provides some examples to help kick-start the work.

#### The strategy is throwing an error

According to the [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40366) from github, the `ValueError: SyncOnReadVariable does not support 'assign_add' .....` is a bug in TensorFlow which is fixed in TF 2.4

You can try to upgrade the tensorflow libraries by

```
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

#### Implementing variables that are not aware of distributed strategy

If you have tried the standard [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras) from the documentation, and it works fine, but your model is not working, you might be having variables that are incorrectly set-up or you are using `distributed variables` that do not have support for the aggregation functions required by the distributed strategy.

As per the TF documentation:

> ..."
> A distributed variable is variables created on multiple devices. As discussed in the glossary, mirrored variable and SyncOnRead variable are two examples.
> "...

To better understand how to implement the custom support for the distributed varialbes, check the following page in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/StrategyExtended)

Comment: is `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` correct way to enforce multiple GPUs on single program?

Comment: Yes, it's the correct one. When the GPUs are on the same host you will be able to distribute the tasks on all of them, or on selected devices. You can read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) from TF documents

Comment: I updated the clarify that this is correct strategy

Comment: I updated tensorflow to 2.4.1 version, but still get away from same error: `ValueError: SyncOnReadVariable does not support `assign_add` in cross-replica context when aggregation is set to `tf.VariableAggregation.SUM`.`. Any idea what's going on? here is full length of error message: [errors](https://gist.github.com/adamFlyn/f7b0b34664f1deab363c56a4ec92f772)

Comment: Can you try the `MNIST` demo, if it works, just to make sure that the `sunny day scenario` is working in your environment. Also, are you using some custom layers or some dependency on the estimatior?

Comment: I used `cifar10`. I am using custom layers, model is similar to CNN. Do you have any better idea for this? Thanks

Comment: If the following [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/custom_training) works, but your project doesn't, the problem might be in the customer layers. This requires further debugging to find out how your customer layers are impacting the aggregation. I will add to the answer about custom aggregation.